# Is there any way to create terminal which can run telnet command on browser from React App with Springboot middleware?

Tags: reactjs, terminal

I'm trying to create an app which can be work same as PUTTY. From where user can connect to the other system over SSH connection. All this process can be display on a browser. It'll be better if looks same like AZUR terminal window.

How to create a terminal which can run telnet command on browser using React?

Comment: A browser is not able to establish raw TCP connections. To build features like this, you will need to make the connection from some server-side application, and then forward messages over Websocket.

Comment: @Evert do you know the steps to do that or any tutorial link to achieve it ? I'm using java spring boot for  server-side application

Comment: No, start googling. Try something and if you get stuck ask _specific questions_.